# What could be the possible reason for Windows removing Password protection for zipped folders?

Tags: windows

I remember in Windows XP, you could set a password to a zipped compressed folder. But in newer Windows OS, the option is not available. Is there any reference which tells why would they remove this feature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows only supports ZipCrypto natively. As ZipCrypto is vulnerable to *known-plaintext attacks* that could easily be exploited e.g. with [bkcrack](https://github.com/kimci86/bkcrack), it should never be used. I don't think it's clearly told anywhere, but I can guess the feature was silently removed (since Windows Vista), because it gave **false sense of security**. However, probably because of the strong backwards compatibility, even Windows 10 can still decrypt those ZipCrypto ZIP files.

7-Zip, WinZip, WinRAR etc. support AES-256 encrypted ZIP-files. The encryption is stronger, but...

- It only encrypts the file contents, not their names. You can circumvent this by first compressing the files into a ZIP and then putting that ZIP into another, AES-256 encrypted ZIP.
- It's not compatible with the native ZIP support in Windows. If you use it, the receiver must have a third party program with the support, too.

Answer (score 1):

The option to encrypt the `zip` files is still there, but Microsoft has done changes to the mechanism - how to do it and the way it works. Now, you would have to zip the file and then right click > `Properties`> `Advanced Attributes` > `Encrypt contents to secure data` > `Apply to folders and sub-folders`. As long as you're logged into your Microsoft account, you will be able to open/extract the contents and other users will not. However, this is not suited for sending as encrypted zip.

I do not know why they'd do something like that, but if I can recommend a great tool for compression/decompression and password protection, I'd like to recommend `7zip`: it's a very powerful FOSS tool.

-Cheers

Comment: That is something else entirely: EFS, an NTFS feature to encrypt files.